# Angular 7 Material Data Table column width and alignment

Tags: css, angular, html-table, angular-material

I got a grid layout. In the top right grid I want to display a dynamic data table.

Problem: I want the data table to align at the top of the grid. Not in the middle like right now. The other thing is, that I want to set the table width as wide as the grid width.

I played with the CSS a little bit, but apparently I didn't find the right CSS attribute or there is something else that I'm missing.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3a8tt

CSS:

```
.example-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 125%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="sender">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sender </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sender}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="recipient">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Empfänger </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.recipient}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Betrag </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="charges">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Gebühr </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.charges}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: Data table]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: You could at *least* provide your CSS.

Comment: What's before `example-container`? Looks like it's not wide enough.

Comment: What do you mean? That's all the code I have. Nothing more. If i put the width of example-container to 200% it gets wider. But if I resize the window, it doesn't change the size and is too big.

Comment: make a stackblitz of your code, then we can help you

Comment: I added the stackblitz @MikeTung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `grid-layout.component.scss` you need to set the child component's height and width in order for your percentages in `transaction-pool.component.css` to do what you want.

so inside `grid-layout.scss`

```
app-transaction-pool {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the transaction pool take up all the space within the grid.

The rest of the styling is up to you.